# Left alignment of tab names

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwidget, qtabwidget, qtabbar

In PyQt5, it is not possible to create tabs on the left and arrange them horizontally by aligning them vertically. You can place it only on the left, but then the tabs will be vertically arranged.
I found a code that allows you to place tabs horizontally on the left, but the names of the tabs are aligned in the middle.
Is it possible to align tabs to the left without the ProxyStyle class?

Image:

[image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
import sys


class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setTabBar(self.TabBar(self))
        self.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.TabPosition.West)

    class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
        def tabSizeHint(self, index):
            s = QtWidgets.QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index)
            s.transpose()
            return s

        def paintEvent(self, event):
            painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
            opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab()

            for i in range(self.count()):
                self.initStyleOption(opt, i)
                painter.drawControl(QStyle.ControlElement.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt)
                painter.save()

                s = opt.rect.size()
                s.transpose()
                r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), s)
                r.moveCenter(opt.rect.center())
                opt.rect = r

                c = self.tabRect(i).center()
                painter.translate(c)
                painter.rotate(90)
                painter.translate(-c)
                painter.drawControl(QStyle.ControlElement.CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt);
                painter.restore()


# class ProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
#     def drawControl(self, element, opt, painter, widget):
#         if element == QStyle.ControlElement.CE_TabBarTabLabel:
#             r = QtCore.QRect(opt.rect)
#             r.setHeight(opt.fontMetrics.horizontalAdvance(opt.text))
#             r.moveBottom(opt.rect.bottom())
#             opt.rect = r
#         # QtWidgets.QProxyStyle.drawControl(self, element, opt, painter, widget)
#         super().drawControl(element, opt, painter, widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    # app.setStyle(ProxyStyle())  # Is it possible to align the names without this class?

    tab = TabWidget()
    tab.setGeometry(0, 0, 5000, 5000)
    tab.addTab(QWidget(), "Tab with a long name")
    tab.addTab(QWidget(), "Tab 2")
    tab.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: I suppose that by "arrange" you actually refer to the *text* of each tab. No, the only alternative would be to manually draw those texts on your own, but there's completely no point in doing that since you already have most of the relevant code, you only need to fix it to your needs. Have you considered *studying* the documentation about QPainter and its painting related classes? Hint: that `42` is probably wrong, and fixed values shouldn't be used (especially when dealing with fonts); try to understand what that code block does and change its behavior to see the results.

Comment: @musicamante, please do not pay attention to 42 because the ProxyStyle class is not supposed to be used at all
I need to make the TabWidget class align tabs to the left, not to the center

Comment: If you want to have vertical text and reliably aligned, you *must* use a QProxyStyle, even using manual painting is *not* acceptable for accurate display. And that 42 may be wrong but also useful to understand the problem: change its value, see what happens. Then read the documentation about QRect and QFontMetrics.

Comment: @musicamante, I managed to get rid of the custom ProxyStyle class and register aligns in the TabWidget class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem (get rid of the custom ProxyStyle class and register the left alignment in the TabWidget.

```py
class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setTabBar(self.TabBar(self))
        self.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.TabPosition.West)

    class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
        def tabSizeHint(self, index):
            s = QtWidgets.QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index)
            s.transpose()
            s.setHeight(int(s.height() * 1.3))  # We increase the height of each panel in which the tab name is placed
            return s

        def paintEvent(self, event):
            painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
            opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab()

            for i in range(self.count()):
                self.initStyleOption(opt, i)
                painter.drawControl(QStyle.ControlElement.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt)
                painter.save()

                r = self.tabRect(i)
                r.moveLeft(r.left() + 20)  # Move the rectangle to the left to align to the left edge
                opt.rect = r

                painter.translate(r.topLeft())
                painter.drawText(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, r.width(), r.height()), QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter, opt.text)
                painter.restore()
```

Comment: That could work for a specific tab bar, yes. It would also have worked better with the proxy style if you just checked the type of the given `widget` argument in the proxy style or eventually setting an internal property.

Comment: @musicamante, no, this class is universal: it adapts to the size of the display and the distance between tabs is set automatically. I tried it in my own program, it worked on my vsp contributions

Comment: It may partially work in a simple case, but you're not considering other important aspects by simply drawing the tabs and texts where you *think* it should be, ignoring disabled tabs or offsets, the tab bar base, possible icons/buttons and mnemonics. Also, you're still using arbitrary values/proportions: that `20` offset causes bleeding/clipping out text if it exceeds the sum of tab margins and minimum tab size (since you simply transposed the size but didn't consider the different orientation). Can you explain why you don't want to use a QProxyStyle, which would make all this much simpler?

Comment: @musicamante, everything works for me. The code has been added a little more, and now it even accepts a picture instead of the name of the tab.I have already tried this class many places, it works as it should everywhere